# Datefield not editable

Tags: blackberry, j2mepolish

I'm using J2ME polish 2.1.2 and trying to add a net.rim.device.api.ui.component.DateField from Blackberry to a tableItem. It displays correctly, but even after setting it to editable, I can't change anything on it. Has anyone else had this experience?

this = tableItem

```
 tfInput = new DateField(_meta.Title, System.currentTimeMillis(), mode);
 //#style textInputCell
    this.set(0, 0, tfInput);      
    this.setSelectionMode(TableItem.SELECTION_MODE_CELL);
```

EDIT: The reason for doing this is because of issues with the Datefield.TIME inputmode on Blackberry if you use J2ME polish's DateField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround for the problem was to extend J2ME Polish's DateField and intercept when setting mode to TIME as follows :

```
public class MyDateField extends DateField{

    public MyDateField (String title, int mode){
        super(title, mode);
        // Blackberry has bug in time mode, so going for date time instead and formatting date
        if (mode == DateField.TIME){
            super.setInputMode(DateField.DATE_TIME);
            super.setDateFormatPattern("HH:mm");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can effectively use DATE_TIME as TIME.